# Relationship between android:noHistory and android:finishOnTaskLaunch

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

How do these two attributes relate? If I have `android:noHistory="true"`, does having `android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"` have any significance/meaning?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Let's say you have three activities in your app: A, B, and C.
You start your app and see A, click a button and see B, click a button and see C.

**First scenario**

Now if you press the Back button on your phone, you will see B.

**Second scenario**

Let's say that B has `android:noHistory="true"`.
Now if you press the Back button on your phone, you will see A. The `android:noHistory="true"` attribute removed B from the history (i.e. the activity stack), so you will not see it when you hit the Back button.

**Third scenario**

Let's say that C has `android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"`.
Now if you press the Home button on your phone and then launch the app again, you will see B. Android ended C when you launched the app again because it has the `android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"` attribute.

Comment: Well explained. How about the other part of the question: If I have `android:noHistory="true"` for an activity, does having `android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"` have any significance/meaning? It feels like the former already "covers" what the latter offers (along with some other side effects as you explained in the second scenario)

Comment: @kolistivra It does not hurt to add it, but maybe you're right; I cannot think of any scenario where it can have any "significance/meaning".

Comment: HI @RacilHilan. I am not sure whether I am right, but I think android:finishOnTaskLaunch will cause the activity to be destroyed as soon as the user presses back or the home button.
So, it is not destroyed when the user relaunched the app, but when the user removed it from foreground. (I suppose internally onPause() calls directly onDestroy())

Answer (score 6):

`finishOnTaskLaunch` would kill the `Activity` as you move to another task. But `noHistory` would kill the `Activity` if you move to another activity in the same task.